# Alpakka Kafka Stream not restarting after connection errors despite using RestartSource

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have a simple committable source for Kafka stream wrapped in RestartSource. It works fine in happy path, but if I deliberately severe the connection to Kafka cluster, it throws connection exception from underlying kafka client and reports Kafka Consumer Shut Down. My expectation was it to restart the stream after ~150 seconds, but it doesn't. Is my understanding/usage of RestartSource incorrect from below:

```
val atomicControl = new AtomicReference[Consumer.Control](NoopControl)
val restartablekafkaSourceWithFlow = {
        RestartSource.withBackoff(30.seconds, 120.seconds, 0.2) {
          () => {
            Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings.withClientId("clientId"), Subscriptions.topics(Set("someTopic")))
              .mapMaterializedValue(c => atomicControl.set(c))
              .via(someFlow)
              .via(httpFlow)
          }
        }
      }
val committerSink: Sink[(Any, ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset), Future[Done]] = Committer.sinkWithOffsetContext(CommitterSettings(actorSystem))

val runnableGraph = restartablekafkaSourceWithFlow.toMat(committerSink)(Keep.both)

val control = runnableGraph.mapMaterializedValue(x => Consumer.DrainingControl.apply(atomicControl.get, x._2)).run()
```

Comment: So it seems that I can add supervision on graph by runnableGraph.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider)) and restart the entire graph if there are connection exception from underlying kafka client. I am not sure why the above source isn't failing however?

Comment: you should provide more details on exception. if it's network issue, committing could also fail (after all committer should also communicate with kafka), but your code covers only source part. if it's really connected with sink you could try to use either `Committer.flowWithOffsetContext` or wrap committing sink in `RestartSink`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting error outside of `RestartSource`.

You can add `recover` to see the error, and/or create a decider like below and use it in `runnableGraph`.

```
private val decider: Supervision.Decider = { e =>
    logger.error("Unhandled exception in stream.", e)
    Supervision.Resume
  }

runnableGraph.withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(decider))
```